# Oracle fusion for Absence Management

Tags: oracle

hi does anyone knows configuration for self service in Oracle fusion for Absence Management for the Absence management tool implementation

Comment: do you expect a yes or no answer ?

Comment: I think you're more likely to get an answer on the Oracle Technet forums dedicated to Apps. [Find them here](https://community.oracle.com/community/oracle-applications)